# MATLAB Nyquist Plot - Show the unit circle

Tags: matlab

I cannot find out how you would show the unit circle centered at -1 on a Nyquist plot.

When I plot `nyquist(L)` with `L(s) = P(s)*C(s)` being my loop function, it only shows the nyquist plot itself. Using `grid on` also doesn't do this.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you create your Nyquist plot, use `hold on;` so we can draw a circle in MATLAB on top of your Nyquist plot.  If you recall from polar co-ordinates, we can parameterize a point on a circle to be the following:

- `x = r*cos(theta);`
- `y = r*sin(theta);`

`r` would be the radius of your circle while `theta` is the angle it makes with respect to the origin.  `theta` has its domain between `[0,2*pi]`.  For the unit circle, `r = 1`.  We would then substitute angles (`theta`) between 0 to `2*pi`.  You also need to shift your circle so that the origin is at `Re = -1, Im = 0`.  As such, do this:

```
n = 1000; %// Define number of points on circle
theta = linspace(0, 2*pi, n);
x = cos(theta);
y = sin(theta);
nyquist(L); %// Spawn Nyquist plot
hold on;
plot(x-1, y); %// Unit circle
```

---

Here's a quick example for you.  Using `L = tf(9, [1 6 9]);` to represent our transfer function of the open-loop system, using the above code produces the following plot:

[image]

Bear in mind that I had to adjust the limits of the axis so you could see the unit circle.  I did this by invoking`axis` in the following way after the plot was shown:

```
axis([-2 2 -1 1]);
```

The real axis limits span from -2 to 2, and the imaginary axis limits span from -1 to 1.

Comment: @lakesh - No problem.  Just wanted to point it out.  I hope I didn't come across as rude.  It actually spawns a new figure that is part of the PDE toolbox, and has widgets and buttons to help solve PDEs where you can draw their domains on where the solutions are valid.  Nyquist plots are part of the Control Systems Toolbox so you unfortunately can't mix those plots together.

Comment: @lakesh - Thank you :) FWIW, I used to teach Control Systems, which is how I knew immediately.

Comment: nice.. i am also from Control,but now in Financial Engineering. I know abt nyquist, but never implemented it via MATLAB.